# Como ler um JSON com campos faltantes para preencher um dicionário?

Tags: python, json, pandas, python-requests, dataframe

Em Python 3 esse código lê a API do Senado Federal, os dados de proposituras:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {"Accept" : "application/json"}

url = 'http://legis.senado.leg.br/dadosabertos/materia/pesquisa/lista?ano=2018'

try:
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
    print ("Http Error:",errh)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
    print ("Error Connecting:",errc) 
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
    print ("Timeout Error:",errt)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
    print ("OOps: Something Else",err)

projetos = r.json()
```

Exemplo do JSON gerado, primeiras linhas:

```
{'PesquisaBasicaMateria': {'@xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
  '@xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation': 'http://legis.senado.gov.br/dadosabertos/dados/PesquisaBasicaMateriav5.xsd',
  'Metadados': {'Versao': '14/01/2019 12:47:04',
   'VersaoServico': '5',
   'DataVersaoServico': '2017-02-01',
   'DescricaoDataSet': 'Efetua a pesquisa de matérias, com a criação de um filtro através dos parâmetros que podem ser informados.\n      Se não informar parâmetro algum, não retorna conteúdo.'},
  'Materias': {'Materia': [{'IdentificacaoMateria': {'CodigoMateria': '132317',
      'SiglaCasaIdentificacaoMateria': 'SF',
      'NomeCasaIdentificacaoMateria': 'Senado Federal',
      'SiglaSubtipoMateria': 'ACE',
      'DescricaoSubtipoMateria': 'AVISO DA COMISSÃO DE EDUCAÇÃO',
      'NumeroMateria': '00001',
      'AnoMateria': '2018',
      'DescricaoIdentificacaoMateria': 'ACE 1/2018',
      'IndicadorTramitando': 'Não'},
     'DadosBasicosMateria': {'EmentaMateria': 'Avalia as medidas adotadas pelo Governo Federal e pelas prefeituras municipais para implementar as estratégias do Plano Nacional de Educação no que concerne à sua Meta 1 (educação infantil), bem como as medidas adotadas pelos entes federativos para promover o funcionamento de creches e pré-escolas construídas com recursos federais por meio do Proinfância.',
      'IndicadorComplementar': 'Não',
      'DataApresentacao': '2018-02-23',
      'NaturezaMateria': {'CodigoNatureza': '304',
       'NomeNatureza': 'DECISAO_TCU',
       'DescricaoNatureza': 'Decisão do Tribunal de Contas da União'}},
     'AutoresPrincipais': {'AutorPrincipal': {'NomeAutor': 'Tribunal de Contas da União',
       'SiglaTipoAutor': 'TRIBUNAL_CONTAS_UNIAO',
       'IndicadorOutrosAutores': 'Não'}},
     'SituacaoAtual': {'Autuacoes': {'Autuacao': {'NumeroAutuacao': '1',
        'Situacao': {'DataSituacao': '2018-03-07',
         'CodigoSituacao': '107',
         'SiglaSituacao': 'CONHECIDA',
         'DescricaoSituacao': 'CONHECIDA.'},
        'Local': {'DataLocal': '2018-03-07',
         'CodigoLocal': '47',
         'SiglaCasaLocal': 'SF',
         'NomeCasaLocal': 'Senado Federal',
         'SiglaLocal': 'CE',
         'NomeLocal': 'Comissão de Educação, Cultura e Esporte'}}}}},
    {'IdentificacaoMateria': {'CodigoMateria': '133324',
      'SiglaCasaIdentificacaoMateria': 'SF',
      'NomeCasaIdentificacaoMateria': 'Senado Federal',
      'SiglaSubtipoMateria': 'ACE',
      'DescricaoSubtipoMateria': 'AVISO DA COMISSÃO DE EDUCAÇÃO',
      'NumeroMateria': '00002',
      'AnoMateria': '2018',
      'DescricaoIdentificacaoMateria': 'ACE 2/2018',
      'IndicadorTramitando': 'Não'},
     'DadosBasicosMateria': {'EmentaMateria': 'Analisa a regularidade do usufruto da isenção de contribuição para a seguridade social das entidades beneficentes de assistência social, com atuação preponderante na área de educação.',
      'IndicadorComplementar': 'Não',
      'DataApresentacao': '2018-05-18',
      'NaturezaMateria': {'CodigoNatureza': '304',
       'NomeNatureza': 'DECISAO_TCU',
       'DescricaoNatureza': 'Decisão do Tribunal de Contas da União'}},
     'AutoresPrincipais': {'AutorPrincipal': {'NomeAutor': 'Tribunal de Contas da União',
       'SiglaTipoAutor': 'TRIBUNAL_CONTAS_UNIAO',
       'IndicadorOutrosAutores': 'Não'}},
     'SituacaoAtual': {'Autuacoes': {'Autuacao': {'NumeroAutuacao': '1',
        'Situacao': {'DataSituacao': '2018-07-10',
         'CodigoSituacao': '107',
         'SiglaSituacao': 'CONHECIDA',
         'DescricaoSituacao': 'CONHECIDA.'},
        'Local': {'DataLocal': '2018-07-10',
         'CodigoLocal': '47',
         'SiglaCasaLocal': 'SF',
         'NomeCasaLocal': 'Senado Federal',
         'SiglaLocal': 'CE',
         'NomeLocal': 'Comissão de Educação, Cultura e Esporte'}}}}},
```

...

Minha intenção é ler o JSON e gerar um dataframe com algumas informações. As informações das proposições começam nesse nível: ["PesquisaBasicaMateria"]["Materias"]["Materia"]
Fiz assim:

```
dados = []
for item in projects["PesquisaBasicaMateria"]["Materias"]["Materia"]:
    dicionario = {"AnoMateria": str(item['IdentificacaoMateria']['AnoMateria']), 
                  "CodigoMateria": str(item['IdentificacaoMateria']['CodigoMateria']), 
                  "DescricaoIdentificacaoMateria": item['IdentificacaoMateria']['DescricaoIdentificacaoMateria'], 
                  "DescricaoObjetivoProcesso": item['IdentificacaoMateria']['DescricaoObjetivoProcesso'], 
                  "DescricaoSubtipoMateria": item['IdentificacaoMateria']['DescricaoSubtipoMateria'], 
                  "IndicadorTramitando": item['IdentificacaoMateria']['IndicadorTramitando'], 
                  "NomeCasaIdentificacaoMateria": item['IdentificacaoMateria']['NomeCasaIdentificacaoMateria'], 
                  "NumeroMateria": str(item['IdentificacaoMateria']['NumeroMateria']), 
                  "DataApresentacao": item['DadosBasicosMateria']['DataApresentacao'], 
                  "DataApresentacao": item['DadosBasicosMateria']['DataApresentacao'], 
                 }
    dados.append(dicionario)

df_prop = pd.DataFrame(dados)
```

Tive esse erro:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-45e13da1fd4f> in <module>
      4                   "CodigoMateria": str(item['IdentificacaoMateria']['CodigoMateria']),
      5                   "DescricaoIdentificacaoMateria": item['IdentificacaoMateria']['DescricaoIdentificacaoMateria'],
----> 6                   "DescricaoObjetivoProcesso": item['IdentificacaoMateria']['DescricaoObjetivoProcesso'],
      7                   "DescricaoSubtipoMateria": item['IdentificacaoMateria']['DescricaoSubtipoMateria'],
      8                   "IndicadorTramitando": item['IdentificacaoMateria']['IndicadorTramitando'],

KeyError: 'DescricaoObjetivoProcesso'
```

O problema é que nem sempre o JSON tem as mesmas chaves de informações em todas as proposições. Por exemplo, 'DescricaoObjetivoProcesso' não aparece em todos as proposições e quando não está não tem valor null, simplesmente é omitida

Por favor, há uma forma de ler o JSON para preencher um dicionário no qual os campos nem sempre estejam presentes? Algo como, se 'DescricaoObjetivoProcesso' não existir então deixar em branco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de preencher o dicionário com a chave desejada você verifica se a chave existe no JSON. Dessa forma:

```
dicionario = {
    "DescricaoObjetivoProcesso": item["DescricaoObjetivoProcesso"] if "DescricaoObjetivoProcesso" in item else None
}
```

Você adiciona `item["DescricaoObjetivoProcesso"]` ao dicionário se ele existe e `None` caso contrário.